Uploaded flutter App on playstore for internal testing, at first it was visible but now it's not showing on playstore
I have a problem, that I uploaded app to the playstore for the internal testing for 20 users. I have invited all 20 users. At first it was showing to all those whom I invited for the testing by their gmails. But now when I or they search it on playstore, then it's not appearing. Also there is another option to share the link of app available in internal testing section in the playstore. But I copy that link and want to access the app. it says,
App not available for this account
Your account hasn't yet been invited to participate in this app's internal testing program.
If you've been invited to become a tester, make sure you're signed in to the account that was invited to the testing program. If you've been invited to a Google Group as part of the program, make sure you've joined the Group.
I have downloaded the app in 9 users mobiles. But the app is no more appearing on playstore.

If your app was initially visible to all users who were invited for internal testing but is no longer appearing, it could be due to changes in the app's status or visibility settings. Make sure that the app is still published for internal testing and that the status is set to "Published" in the Play Console.

Be sure that the track is not paused in Google Play console. If paused, resume it and it will work immeditely.
